# OpenCV pass data from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

With `opencv` in Python I was having trouble trying to make SIFT work ( [here's the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597130/cannot-run-sift-with-opencv-on-macos) ), so I implemented what I needed in C++, here's the code in the main.cpp:

```
  cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  auto sift = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
  vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoint;
  sift->detect(src, keypoint);
  cv::Mat descriptor;
  sift->compute(src, keypoint, descriptor);
```

the things that I need are the vector of  `KeyPoint`s and the descriptor matrix.

Now I would like to continue with Python since I need numpy and I need a way to transfer the vectors.

**Is there a way to move the vectors to Python?**

For the matrix I could write it to a file and then read it from python, but I don't know what to to with the vector of KeyPoints.

I was thinking I could move the code into a function, compile it as a shared library and try to import it with something like the cffi but for C++, the problem is that I have little experience with this and I think there would be problem with the handling of types.

Comment: You would usually write a Cython wrapper to pass data between C++ and Python but looking at your other post which I've now answered, this should no longer be required as you should now be able to use SIFT within Python so there's no need for this C++ and Python bridge anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should enumerate a **std::vector** and convert each C++ **KeyPoint** object.
Since you want to convert key points into a matrix, do like this.

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> points;
...
cv::Mat_<float> mat(points.size(), 7);
for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
    auto& p = points[i];
    mat.row(i) <<
        p.pt.x, p.pt.y, p.size, p.angle, p.response, p.octave, p.class_id;
}
```